# Can oAuth 2.0 server be used instead of or replace oAuth 1.0 server?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, user-experience

oAuth ver 2 introduces additional flows to the specification, and user experience of trusted projects could be improved a lot. For example: by using on-page username/password submission. This also increases the conversions by having username/password form in your checkout form. This is introduced in version 2.

Hence the question:
Can oAuth 2.0 server completely replace oAuth 1.0 server?

Comment: I understand that oauth 2.0 is not in the final draft yet and subject to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google is even using OAuth 2 exclusively for several of their APIs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Have you tried to or know of someone who authenticates using oauth 1.0 client with oauth 2.0 server?

Comment: 1 and 2 are not compatible so a 1 client won't work on a 2 server. OAuth 1 has a complex signature process while OAuth 2 is basically just passing a secret with each request.

Comment: I think oauth 2 is much more than "passing a secret" with each request. There are great new "authentication flows" and one of them is similar to the one used in oauth 1. That's why I asked this question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The auth flows are just how you get a token. Once you have that token you just pass it to the server with requests. Some of the flows are similar because they are designed for different use cases and both versions need to cover those same use cases.